# Sharepoint Online: How to share just a page, not the whole site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have a SharePoint Online site. I have created a few sub pages on this site. I want people in group A to only access page 1 and I want people in group B to only access page 2. When I grant access in Site Permissions, it only controls access to the entire site (and all pages within). When I try to use the Share feature instead, it changes the URL of the page. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to break permission inheritance and add unique permissions to your pages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set permissions on a single page within a site , here are steps:

1.In Site Content go to the Site Pages library.

2.Select the page for which you want to set permissions and click manage access.

3.Stop Inheriting permissions

3.Then set the permissions on a page level the same way you would set permissions on a document, folder or site.

Check out the motion picture of my operation:
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.